# How to force a file location in equivs-build

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have some files that I would like to install using `.deb` files created using `equivs-build`. What I cannot understand is the syntax required in the `.equivs` file.

This is my file layout:

```
myapp.equivs
myapp/
  files/
    script.sh
```

What I want to tell `equivs-build` is to install the `script.sh` file at `/usr/share/myapp/script.sh`. I did some tests, but none of the following syntaxes for `Files` seems to work as intended.

**Test 1**

```
Files: ./myapp/files/script.sh /usr/share/myapp/script.sh
```

Result: file installed in `/usr/share/myapp/script.sh/myapp/files/script.sh`.

**Test 2**

```
Files: ./demo/files/script.sh /usr/share/myapp/
```

Result: file installed in `/usr/share/myapp/myapp/files/script.sh`.

**Test 3**

```
Files: ./demo/files/script.sh /usr/share/myapp
```

Result: file installed in `/usr/share/myapp/myapp/files/script.sh`.

How can I instruct equivs-build to install a file at an arbitrary location?

Comment: It looks like this is known bug: <http://bugs.debian.org/662946>.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I think that equivs was build to create very simple packages only. Not packages with a deeper source directory structure.

As a workaround I "fixed" the equivs-build perl script as follows:

`/usr/bin/equivs-build` (around line 70):

```
die "Cannot parse Files line: '$_'\n" unless m:^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)/?\s*$:;
#$install_files{"$2/$1"} = $1;
$install_files{"$2"} = $1;    # do not append source path to target path
```

Now you specify full source and target paths with filename in the control file. I.e.

```
Files: opt/sounds/test.wav /opt/sounds/test.wav
 opt/sounds/test4.wav /opt/sounds/default.wav
```

Via that method you can use an arbitrary deep source dir structure. As a benefit you can also specify a different target filename if needed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I already applied a similar patch to my local `equivs-build`, see https://github.com/gioele/createdeb/issues/1#issuecomment-19374130